# JQuery UI autocomplete source function ajax webservice call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, jquery-ui

I need some help in my Jquery source function which is using an Ajax webservice call. I am getting data in autocomplete but,

1. As user type, it's currently not providing any suggestions..
2. How to highlight the text.

### My HTML

```
    <body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <select id="combobox">              
        </select>
    </div>
    </body>
```

### Jquery

```
_source: function (request, response) {       
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/Automobile.asmx/GetCarList") %>',
                      data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                      dataType: "json",
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      success: function (data) {
                          response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                              return {
                                  label: item.split('-')[0],
                                  val: item.split('-')[1]
                              }
                          }))
                      },
                  });

                  var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                  response(this.element.children().map(function (data) {
                      var text = data.d;
                      if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                          return {
                              label: text,
                              value: text

                          };
                  }));
                 },
```

Comment: `.suggesting-user` is not anywhere in the supplied code.  Is this a class, html element, method, or what?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, my code is not providing any suggestions when user start typing.

Comment: Is this a segment of an `.autocomplete` widget?  Can you include more context?

Comment: yes, I am using Jquery UI autocomplete see the source here. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: I am, unfortunately at a loss. :\

Comment: I haven't changed anything except source function and HTML compare to Jquery UI widget

Comment: I realize that, but I do not know what is causing your issue. That is what I mean.

Comment: What's `_source`...? What is the structure of `data`..? Why are you calling `response` twice..?

Comment: Please see the jquery ui link for autocomplete widget in the above comment for more clarifications. Also, I know I have to call response only once but I can't see ajax jquery work for ajax call and select highlight text and sort based on what user type that's the issue I am still working on..